# Examine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n(\log_2n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Examine the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n(\log_2n)}$

**My Work:**

Make $x_n=\frac1{n(\log_2n)}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ must be equal to zero if this series converges. It is equal to zero as the denominator will approach infinity as n approaches infinity.

Neither the root test, nor the ratio test appears to be useful in this scenario. The series is also not geometric. I am currently trying to figure out a comparison test that I can use but nothing is coming to mind. Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Just some background information, this is one of my practice problems for an upcoming exam in my analysis course.

Comment: Have you learned the integral test yet?

Comment: We have not learned that yet

Comment: The series cannot begin at $1$ since $\log_2 1=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Key Point :** Use Cauchy's condensation test.

Let , $\displaystyle f(n)=\frac{1}{n\log_2 n}=\frac{\log_e 2}{n\log_e n}$. Let $a(>1)$ be a real number. Then , $$a^nf(a^n)=\frac{a^n \log 2}{a^n n\log a}=\frac{\log 2}{\log a}.\frac{1}{n}.$$As $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent so $\displaystyle \sum a^nf(a^n)$ is divergent and hence series $\displaystyle \sum f(n)$ is divergent.

Comment: Really like Cauchy condensation test! I remember thinking it was very cool when we saw it in our first real analysis course! Although we only did the a=2 case :)

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

First, write $\log_2n=\frac{\log n}{\log 2}$.  Then, note that since $\frac{\log 2}{n\log n}$ is strictly decreasing for $n\ge 2$, we have for all $N\ge 2$ the inequality

$$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n\log_2 n}=\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{\log 2}{n\log n}\ge\int_2^{N+1}\frac{\log 2}{x\log x}\,dx$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 4):

**Divergence**

Using the inequality
$$
\log(1+x)\le x\tag{1}
$$
twice, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\log(\log(n+1))
&=\log\left(\log(n)+\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)\\
&=\log(\log(n))+\log\left(1+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\log(n)}\right)\\
&\le\log(\log(n))+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\log(n)}\\
&\le\log(\log(n))+\frac1{n\log(n)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
\frac1{n\log(n)}\ge\log(\log(n+1))-\log(\log(n))\tag{3}
$$
Summing $(3)$, and noticing that the sum on the right [telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), we see that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^m\frac1{n\log_2(n)}
&=\log(2)\sum_{n=2}^m\frac1{n\log(n)}\\
&\ge\log(2)[\log(\log(m+1))-\log(\log(2))]\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Since the right side of $(4)$ grows without bound, the series on the left side diverges.

---

**Asymptotic Behavior**

First of all,
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log_2(k)}
=\log(2)\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log(k)}\tag{5}
$$
Using The [Euler Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we get
$$
\hspace{-1cm}\small\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log(k)}
=\log(\log(n))+C+\frac1{2n\log(n)}-\frac1{12n^2\log(n)}-\frac1{12n^2\log(n)^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4\log(n)}\right)\tag{6}
$$
where
$$
C=0.7946786454528994022038979620651495140650\tag{7}
$$
In any case, $(6)$ means that $(5)$ diverges.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? The Cauchy Condensation Test and The Integral Test are the two tests I would suggest. However, I think it is interesting that the sum gets closer and closer to $\log(2)\log(\log(n))+C$ for some constant, $C$.

Comment: I have added a more elementary approach that uses the comparison test and the inequality $(3)$.